# COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R 777 logs after failstart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, administrator

I'm trying to resolve Ubuntu 14.04 (mostly SSH) failstart. I've spotted some suspicious commands executed by one of the developers. Since they were executed, I was not able to access it using SSH anymore.

```
root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/www/html/projects/at2/htdocs/public ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R 777

root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/www/html/projects/at2/htdocs/public ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R 777 ./images

root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/www/html/projects/at2/htdocs/public ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R 777 . /
```

After that log file is full of messages like

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

What exactly each command did and how can I rollback them?

Comment: You shouldn't give so much power to your developers.

Comment: `and how can I rollback them` You can not roll it back.Unless you have an OS/FS backup, or if you are able to restore the permissions from a sister-system. (but that is serious scripting ...)

Comment: Yes. I totally agree with you. At least this happened on our 'personal' server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't give that much power to your developers and I would recommend re-installing the whole system instead of fixing all incorrect permissions.

The last command has set access rights of all files to 777 which means give right to read, write and list to user, group and everyone else.

The problem is that ssh doesn't like incorrectly set permissions and fails to start then. To fix this problem and to get immediate access you can use the following command:

```
chmod 600 -R /etc/ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R 777 . /
```

This was likely a typo. They wanted to run `chmod -R 777 ./` and got a space in between.

This made all files on the system readable and writable by any user. SSH will reject logins now, because anybody can modify the host private key, which means nobody can be trusted to log in. But this is only one of the issues. Your `sudo` access will likely be broken as well, as well as many other things.

You can't roll this back. (or at least not without spending a considerable amount of time) You'll have to reinstall the whole host most likely. (much faster option) At this point ssh connections will be rejected.

I guess the only steps now are:

- figure out how to obtain a copy of the affected system, so you have a full backup of anything you need
- learn about file privileges and why no file should ever have mode `0777`
- teach the developer about file privileges and why no file should ever have mode `0777`